# Trying to connect from DataStax Studio to my Astra cluster - Connection test failed

Tags: cassandra, connection, datastax-astra, datastax-studio

Just got my brand new 6.8 DataStax Astra (Cassandra) and downloaded studio from https://www.datastax.com/dev/datastax-studio. My Nodejs connection works great. But trying connect from Studio - everything fails with SSL configurations:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed.. (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
```

It looks like port should be 29080 as per secure-connect .. /config.json
I used API User Admin Token for Client and Secret keys.

Not sure if it's related but python connection fails with:

```
...cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers'
...Unauthorized('Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="No SELECT permission on <table system_virtual_schema.keyspaces>"')
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't connect to Astra because it's connecting to the wrong CQL port.

The correct port configuration is in the `cqlshrc` file in the `[connection]` section. For example:

```
[connection]
hostname = db-uuid-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com
port = 39876
ssl = true
```

This is the correct CQL port to use to connect from Studio or other clients. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 6.8 Astra is currently using port 29042 by default.
Both Python connector and Studio work great under Admin User credentials, but not under the Admin API User. So the authorization error message was ligid. NodeJS works great with Admin API User credentials..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Astra doesn't have a default CQL port -- each DB instance is allocated a random port and `29042` is not the default. Cheers!